# setIcon is not displaying images at all

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have tried every possible solutioin online but nothing seems to work. I am trying to display flags for my Flag guessing game. I am setting the icon for JLabel **flagIconJLabel** in the **displayFlag()**  function but it doesn't actually show the flag image when I run the program. I don't see any bugs so I am stuck. The path is fine I can display images by themselves.
Please Help :/

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class FlagQuiz extends JFrame{
  private String[] countries = { "Russia", "China", "United States",
      "Italy", "Australia", "South Africa", "Brazil", "Spain" };

  private boolean[] flagsUsed = new boolean[countries.length];
  private int currentIndex;
  private int count = 1;
  private JPanel flagJPanel;
  private JLabel flagIconJLabel;
  private JLabel selectCountryJLabel;
  private JComboBox selectCountryJComboBox;
  private JTextField feedbackJTextField;
  private JButton submitJButton;
  private JButton nextFlagJButton;

  public FlagQuiz() {
    createUserInterface();
  }

  private void createUserInterface(){
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    flagJPanel = new JPanel();
    flagJPanel.setBounds(16, 8, 100, 90);
    flagJPanel.setLayout(null);
    flagJPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Flag"));
    contentPane.add(flagJPanel);

    flagIconJLabel = new JLabel();
    flagIconJLabel.setBounds(10, 14, 80, 80);
    flagIconJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    flagJPanel.add(flagIconJLabel);

    selectCountryJLabel = new JLabel();
    selectCountryJLabel.setBounds(136, 8, 88, 21);
    selectCountryJLabel.setText("Select country:");
    contentPane.add(selectCountryJLabel);

    Arrays.sort(countries);

    selectCountryJComboBox = new JComboBox(countries);
    selectCountryJComboBox.setBounds(136, 32, 135, 21);
    selectCountryJComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
    contentPane.add(selectCountryJComboBox);

    displayFlag();

    // set up feedbackJTextFiel

    feedbackJTextField = new JTextField();
    feedbackJTextField.setBounds(136, 64, 135, 32);
    feedbackJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(
        JTextField.CENTER);
    feedbackJTextField.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(feedbackJTextField);

    submitJButton = new JButton();
    submitJButton.setBounds(287, 8, 88, 32);
    submitJButton.setText("Submit");
    contentPane.add(submitJButton);
    submitJButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            submitJButtonActionPerformed(event);}}
    );

    // set up nextFlagJButton
    nextFlagJButton = new JButton();
    nextFlagJButton.setBounds(287, 48, 88, 32);
    nextFlagJButton.setText("Next Flag");
    nextFlagJButton.setEnabled(false);
    contentPane.add(nextFlagJButton);
    nextFlagJButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            nextFlagJButtonActionPerformed(event);}}
    );

    setTitle("Flag Quiz");
    setSize(390, 135);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private int getUniqueRandomNumber(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randomNumber;
    do{
      randomNumber = generator.nextInt(8);}
    while (flagsUsed[randomNumber] == true);
    flagsUsed[randomNumber] = true;
    return randomNumber; }

  private void displayFlag(){
    currentIndex = getUniqueRandomNumber();
    String country =
        (String) selectCountryJComboBox.getItemAt(currentIndex);
    String countryPath = "images/" + country + ".png";
    flagIconJLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(countryPath));}

  private void submitJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if (selectCountryJComboBox.getSelectedIndex()
        == currentIndex){
      feedbackJTextField.setText("Correct!");}
    else{
      feedbackJTextField.setText("Sorry, incorrect.");}
    if (count == 5){
      feedbackJTextField.setText(
          feedbackJTextField.getText() + "   Done!");
      nextFlagJButton.setEnabled(false);
      submitJButton.setEnabled(false);
      selectCountryJComboBox.setEnabled(false); }
    else{
      submitJButton.setEnabled(false);
      nextFlagJButton.setEnabled(true);}}

  private void nextFlagJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    displayFlag();
    count++;
    feedbackJTextField.setText("");       
    selectCountryJComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    submitJButton.setEnabled(true);
    nextFlagJButton.setEnabled(false);}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    FlagQuiz application = new FlagQuiz();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);}}
```

Comment: Consider 1) creating and posting a valid [mre] code post with your question, formatting the code so that it is readable

Comment: `while (flagsUsed[randomNumber] == true);` 

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` will look for the image relative to the current execution context of the app, which might be different from where the app is actually installed.  You may be better of embedded the images within the context of the app, which will, generally, make there retrial easier

Comment: *"every possible solution"* Don't make such claims lightly. In this case, if you'd read 'every possible solution' you'd have stumbled across references  to embedded resources & how to load them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , it's working for me , i have the image in same package though , but you can send relative path too, I am using other constructor of imageicon where passing URL i tried passing image path as string didn't work for me

```
   protected static ImageIcon createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = YourClass.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description));
        }
    }
```